# how to correctly display result from SEOStats library's getSerps method on google.ch search?

Tags: php, api, seo, statistics

I am using SEOStats library's getSerps method to query google.ch for particular keyword. When I do that result is having "?". I believe they are from swiss language's special characters.

I want to display them correctly on web page. I have already tried utf8_encode and utf8_decode functions with no luck.

If you want to generate this issue on your side then just make following change on SEOstats\Config\DefaultSettings.php file.

```
const GOOGLE_TLD = 'ch';
```

And call example/get-google-serps.php file with keyword "web hosting". You will see many '?' in resulting php array.

Thanks for help in advance.

Bhavesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've installed SEOStats via composer `composer require seostats/seostats`. If you download library from github it may differ.

Here is line from my `\vendor\seostats\seostats\SEOstats\Services\Google.php`:

```
$curledSerp = utf8_decode( self::gCurl($nextSerp, $ref) );
```

Here is `utf8_decode` function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php). This function converts all utf8 chars to iso. All chars that cannot be converted by this function are replaced with `?` Try to **remove utf8_decode function** and you'll have all your utf-8 chars safe.